# How do I use the Facebook Login Button from the Facebook Developers site in a React component?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a Ruby on Rails app with React on the frontend to which I would like to add Facebook authentication.
I'm following along the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) on Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK. At one point it says:

> Including the Login Button into your page is easy. Visit the
>   documentation for the login button and set the button up the way you
>   want. Then click Get Code and it will show you the code you need to
>   display the button on your page.

The aforementioned documentation is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button). On the latter link, there is a "plugin configurator" where you

> set the button up the way you want

.  When I click on "Get code" I am instructed to:

1) Paste this code right after my opening body tag of my html page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=myAppId";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2) "Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.", the code being:

**`<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false"></div>`**

I pasted the latter piece of code in my Reactjs app, inside the render function of a component. I expected this to give me a facebook button that is styled already. I get nothing.

When I paste that piece of code directly in my application.html template, I do see the button. Therefore, I guess this is an issue with the code being inside the JSX code of a React component.

How do I use the facebook login button in a Reactjs app?

Comment: this is confusing. Are you saying that the button doesn't appear at all on your page? If so this isn't a styling issue and it's more to do with how you're using the sdk

Comment: Well, I just paste that div into my page. Actually, I'm using React, so it goes into JSX code in a render function. The div appears in the html, it just has no height.

Comment: And that is it. Found the problem. It has to do with using React. When I paste that div in my application.html directly, it works, I see the facebook button as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the fb supplied html snippet to be rendered exactly as-is you need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to insert the raw HTML.  Otherwise react is going to fool around with the html, and that is what I suspect is causing the problem (as demonstrated by your experiment in sticking the html outside of any react component)

More on doing this here: http://facebook.github.io/react/index.html (see the last example on the landing page) and https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

FYI if u are just building this app and are in rails you might want to checkout http://reactrb.org

Comment: To insert the raw HTML into what? And why is this exactly? I actually have the div above inside of a form element. I already had the latter fully styled, and now that I'm simply adding a button to sign in via facebook, I'm just adding the facebook button inside of the form.